# Are there any Desktop environments that work in the SSH environment?

Tags: desktop-environment, software-rec, remote-desktop, slackware

Basically I am looking for an ASCII desktop environment, that I can run in the terminal environment, and exit to the terminal. Think the Links2 browser for Ubuntu. Except with the ability of a desktop environment. If this is the wrong place to ask, I apologise. Anyway, the distro I use is Slackware Linux.

Comment: Is there an X11 server at the _local_ end of your SSH connection?  Can there be one?  Have you decided not to run one even if there can?  Because if that's  your limitation, that needs to be in the question to head off the obvious responses.

Comment: Do you require actual point-and-click interaction, or would running a few shells in multiple `tmux` panes and/or windows be enough? (This is how I work on my OpenBSD and NetBSD systems from macOS).

Comment: Yeah that would work perfectly, don't need a mouse, essentially all I need is an application manager.

Comment: You might want to clarify the question, based on your subsequent responses to some of the answers given.

Answer (score 2):

All X11: if you run `ssh` with the `-X` option. And your run it in an X11 environment. From your desktop, open a terminal, type `ssh -X ...`, then when you are logged in, launch a program that will open a window (e.g. `xeyes`).

Another option is to
tunnel VNC over `ssh`. `ssvnc` makes this easy.

Comment: How would I do this?

Comment: What desktop are you running at your end?

Comment: I don't have one, but I found texttop. The reason I am not installing XFCE is because it did not work

Comment: So you don't use any graphical desktop at all. Cool, but why?

Comment: it doesn't work, as it breaks my installation for some reason

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not looking for a desktop environment, rather for a terminal multiplexer like `tmux` or `screen`.